# Babel issue babel-preset-react-app . The react app stopped working for me suddenly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

One of your dependencies, babel-preset-react-app, is importing the "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object" package without declaring it in its dependencies. This is currently working because "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object" is already in your node_modules folder for unrelated reasons, but it may break at any time.

I have recently started facing this issue

I tried this following command and. it worked for me
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.